# Complex Postgres Query Issues

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, inner-join, aggregate-functions

Working on building a query at work for hotel program participation. I have a table dwp_list that has hotelcode (fk) and programname as the other column, plus a table all_hotels that lists all the hotel information using hotelcode as the primary key. What I am trying to do (with no success) is add columns for each programname to create a total participation report. Please see the image for better description. I have tried using the EXISTS function but the subquery is returning more than one record.

There are a total of 18 different programs, so one I figure out how to do one, I can manage the rest pretty easily, but its a pain to do manually.

[image: Excel Example]

Comment: Do you have a question?  If so, you should ask it.

Comment: You'd have to define more clearly what a "total participation report" is for you. People are also more willing to help if you show your efforts so far, ideally in the form of an SQL statement, and describe where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, sorry for the vagueness, new to this Stack Overflow thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed list of program names, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select h.*,
    max(case when l.programname = 'AAA' then 'x' end) as aaa,
    max(case when l.programname = 'BBB' then 'x' end) as bbb,
    max(case when l.programname = 'CCC' then 'x' end) as ccc
from all_hotels h
inner join dwp_list l on l.hotelcode = h.hotelcode
group by h.hotelcode
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!